# define static function outside the class and access static value .h and .cc files

Tags: c++, class, static

```
 //foo.h
 class Foo 
  {
    private:
      static int number;

    public: 
      static int bar();
  };

//foo.cc
#include "foo.h"

 int Foo::bar() 
 {
   return Foo::number;
 }
```

this is not working. I want to define a static function outside the class definition and access a static value.

```
undefined reference to `Foo::number'
```

Comment: The static value was never defined. Add `int Foo::number;` in foo.cc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just declared the static member you need to define it too.
Add this in your cpp file.

```
int Foo::number = 0;
```

This should be a good read:

**[what is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)**

Comment: thanks! I didn t know that this is possible when settig Foo::number as private

Answer (score 2):

you have to define `Foo::number`:

```
// foo.cc
...
int Foo::number(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared Foo::number you have to add a definition.  In your cpp file Add this line

```
int Foo::number = 0;
```